# CodeIgniter, getJSON parse error: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Tags: ajax, json, codeigniter, getjson, parse-error

I am making a jquery ajax call with getJSON on a CodeIgniter PHP page, but the echoed json string contains unexpected character at line 1 column 1.
Actually it is a wierd characted (on Chrome console is represented by a red point) and is prepended to any echo: if I remove from the php file the json output together with any other output (i.e. the code does nothing), still the weird character is printed (I can see it from Chrome's console). 
Also, if I call directly the page with the browser the weird character is not visible (also inspecting the code).
The Ajax response is fine: status 200 and, except the wierd character, the format is valid.
It seems that something is prepended to the output by the framework itself.

Some info about my Codeigniter configuration:
 - ver 3.0
 - i18n
 - Twig
 - HMVC

JS libraries:
 - jQuery v2.1.3
 - jQuery-iu v1.11.4

PHP code snippet:

```
    $productionHierArr = array(
        "productionHier" => $productionHier,
        "dictionary" => $this->lang->language           
    );

    $this->output->set_content_type('application/json');
    echo json_encode($productionHierArr);
```

As a final note, the same code was working perfectely on my previous envirorment on CodeIgniter 2.2.1 with no HMVC.
Thanks for any help.

**EDIT**

This the JS code:

```
var ajaxHier = $.getJSON("item/getProductionHierJson");

$.when( ajaxHier ).done(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
    initHier(data);
})
.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log("error: ", textStatus);
    console.log("errorThrown: ", errorThrown);
});
```

Comment: try commenting this line $this->output->set_content_type('application/json');

Comment: I think $this->lang->language might be issue try `$this->lang->line('sample')`

Comment: Unfortunately is not the content_type nor the language function.
I have already commented out both of them, also commenting everything (= no echo), but the unrecognizable character is still there. Alone, but still there.

Comment: Also moved the php code to another module getting the same problem.
Is there any way I can see all the complete output, header included, sent to the page by the server? (I am running Apache under XAMPP)

Comment: I have found the problem!! I made complete new install of the envirorment checking the ajax call after each step, and it turned out that the problem is my routing rule (that I took as it is from the i18n library):


**$route['^(en|it)/(.+)$'] = "$2";**


this routing adds the wierd character. Anyone can figure out why??

Comment: Actually is not only the routing rule, anykind of routing, for what I can see about ajax call, is adding that unwanted character. Here is my .htaccess:
   
    
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule .* index.php?/$0 [PT,L]

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome, red dots usually represent non-printable special unicode characters.

Please check your server side code to prevent outputting those characters

**Edit**
better to encode them with UTF-8 without BOM. This can be easily done through notepad++. The steps are as follows,

Open your files in notepad++.
Go to Encoding option on the file menu.
Then select the option "convert to UTF-8 without BOM".
This may resolve your problem.

Comment: Thank you but I have already set that up. Double checked again right now and it is UTF-8 without BOM.

Comment: can you var_dump the $productionHierArr and put the content here ?

Answer (score 0):

For other people who may step into the same problem, this is the solution I found after two days of investigation:
it turned out that the file "MY_Lang.php" in "core" folder was encoded in UTF8 **with** BOM while it should have been, of course, UTF8 **without** BOM.
Fortunately I had a working version of this stuff and comparing detail by detail I could solve the enigma.
Anyway, @Sekai was on the right track, (sorry, not enough reputation for a +1), thank you.